# Ag-Grid loads data but won't display it

Tags: javascript, java, ag-grid

I'm using Ag-Grid to try and display a series of search results from a database. Almost everything works, the grid table appears, the search field, button, etc. all work, the correct REST interface is called and the data is returned as a Java List...for the example I'm using there are 16 results, and when I run the search what I basically see is 16 blank rows appear in the grid. It seems that it's getting as far as realizing it needs to populate the 16 entries, but something I've misconfigured prevents it from doing so. The event listener even works and kicks off the proper method, it's just that since nothing appears in the individual rows, the arg it collects is just null. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Here is the HTML:

```
        <div id="SearchTable" ng-controller="docSearch">
            <div class="searchlabel">
                Search Keyword Libraries<br> Search: <input name="searchField"
                    placeholder="Search..." type="text" ng-model="data.searchField" />
                <button ng-click='searchKeywordLibs(data.searchField)'>Find</button>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div ag-grid="SearchKeywordsTableGrid"
                style="width: 500px; height: 200px;" class="ag-fresh"></div>
            <div ng-if="status" id="status">
                <b layout="row" layout-align="start center" class="md-padding">
                </b>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the grid definition:

```
$scope.SearchKeywordsTableGrid = {
    columnDefs : [ {
        headerName : 'Keyword Library Name',
        editable : false,
        filter: 'text'
    },
    {
        headerName : 'Path',
        editable : false,
        filter: 'text'
    },      
    ],
    rowSelection: 'single',
    enableSorting: true,
    enableColResize: true,
    enableFilter: true,
    suppressLoadingOverlay: true,
    suppressNoRows: true,
    sizeColumnsToFit: true
};
```

And here is the controller function:

```
$scope.searchKeywordLibs = function(search_term) {
    $http.get('/trm/get_keyword_search_results?search_term='+search_term).success(
    function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.SearchKeywordsTableGrid.api.setRowData($scope.data);

        // add event listener
        if($scope.SearchKeywordsTableGrid.api != 'undefined') {
            $scope.SearchKeywordsTableGrid.api.addEventListener('rowDoubleClicked', openSearchResultPage);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: what are the `keys` of the returned objects from your http request?

Comment: Aha! That was it (sorry, been staring at this for a while)...the keys are 'name' and 'path'...when I add field: 'name' and field: 'path' to the column definitions it works. Not sure if that was going to be your specific suggestion, but thanks for the nudge Jarod!

Comment: Yep that was what I was going to suggest. `field` is required so that the grid knows where to pull the data for that cell from. Well... `field` is required, unless you have a `cellRenderer` defined

Answer (score 0):

Okay Jarod's comment steered me to where I needed to be...it was a simple flub, I didn't have the field attributes defined in the column definitions. It should have been:

```
$scope.SearchKeywordsTableGrid = {
    columnDefs : [ {
        headerName : 'Keyword Library Name',
        field: 'name',
        editable : false,
        filter: 'text'
    },
    {
        headerName : 'Path',
        field: 'path',
        editable : false,
        filter: 'text'
    },      
    ],
    rowSelection: 'single',
    enableSorting: true,
    enableColResize: true,
    enableFilter: true,
    suppressLoadingOverlay: true,
    suppressNoRows: true,
};
```

Thanks!